# Find image and kernel of $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $x \mapsto i$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider the homomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $x
\mapsto i$. Find:
(a) the image;
(b) the kernel;
(c) exhibit the
  bijection of the Correspondence Theorem explicitly for $\mathbb{Z}[x]
  \twoheadrightarrow \text{im}(\varphi)$.  (Hint for (c): you should
  probably use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, the Gaussian integers, is a
  PID!)

Intuitively, the image seems to be all Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. How do I prove this?

EDIT: $(x-i) \subseteq \text{ker}(\varphi)$. The kernel seems to be the ideal generated by $(x^2+1)$. $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1) \cong \mathbb{Z}[i]$. How do I prove this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is $x-i \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$? In other words, would you say that $i \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Note that a polynomial $p(X)$ goes to $p(i)$. You should convince yourself the kernel is $(X^2+1)$, and the image is $\Bbb Z[i]$, which gives the isomorphism $\Bbb Z[X]/(X^2+1)\simeq \Bbb Z[i]$.

Comment: They are already telling you the image is the Gaussian integers implicitly. Also, saying "consider the homomorphism that maps $x$ to $i$" is meaningless unless you have already seen that such a homomorphism always exists and is unique, I think this is sometimes called the universal property of the ring of polynomials.

Comment: any more help? particularly c?

Answer (score 1):

how it is possible that x-i in kernel,because x-i is not in domain,but x^2+1 is in kernel .now if a polynomial  p(x) is in kernel then p(i)=0, similarly p(-i)=0,
now you can see that p(x) must have a factor x^2+1 in domain ring. this proves the the statement

Comment: Wlecome to math.SE! This answer needs you to [edit it](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Your first observation is correct (but poorly written when it comes to puntuaction). The second one is *always false*: $p\in\ker\varphi\Leftrightarrow p(i)-1=-1$, obviously.